# Assembly not being located in GAC but gacutil shows it's there

Tags: c#, .net, gac, .net-assembly, global-assembly-cache

I have noticed some strange behaviour on my system regarding the Global Assembly Cache (GAC). The assembly I'm interested in is log4net Version=**1.2.11.0**

The output of `gacutil /l "log4net"` is:

> C:\Windows\system32>gacutil /l "log4net" Microsoft (R) .NET Global
>   Assembly Cache Utility.  Version 4.0.30319.1 Copyright (c) Microsoft
>   Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> The Global Assembly Cache contains the following assemblies:
>   log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821, processorArchitecture=MSIL
>   log4net, Version=1.2.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a, processorArchitecture=MSIL
>
> Number of items = 2

However viewing the GAC through the explorer shell (before and after a restart) only shows one version:

[image]

This is compounded by the fact that my application cannot resolve the assembly, but works fine when I place it into the *application base* (bin folder).  According to [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15hyw9x3%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) the GAC will be probed **before** the application base - which would point to the assembly not being in the GAC.

So is `log4net Version=1.2.11.0` in the GAC?  If so why can't my application locate it?

Comment: I don't understand the -1 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking in the .NET 2.0 GAC, however, log4net v1.2.11.0 is a .NET 4 assembly.  .NET 4 has its own GAC which is located in `%winddir%\Microsoft.NET\Assembly`.  Check the GAC_MSIL directory in there and I'll bet you'll find it.

Comment: I had no idea it was separated out!  I can confirm it does appear to be in there, but why won't my app resolve to it?

Comment: Is your app .NET 3.5 or 4.x?